# How to access array properties with Laravel Eloquent, if stored in a database?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

For example, I have JSON stored in a Row of a database called 'data'

External.php (model) - casting 'data' to an array:

```
protected $casts = [
    'data' => 'array',
];
```

I can access it using Tinker with this commmand:

```
$external = App\External::first()->pluck('data');
```

This returns

```
 Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3384
     all: [
       [
         "id" => 17566616456845,
         "name" => "#1008",
         "note" => "",
         "tags" => "",
         "test" => false,
         "email" => "katie.jane@example.com",
         "phone" => null,

         ...
         ..
         .
```

How do I access the "email" or "id" from that collection? How do I modify the tinker eloquent command to get the "id" or "email"?

> **$external = App\External::all()->pluck('data')->'email'**
>
> T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' on line 1> Exception with message 'Property [email] does not exist on this>  PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING,
>   expecting

Getting warmer:

```
>>> $external = App\External::pluck('data')->get('email')
=> null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pluck() method returns array. So if you want to access 'email' you must use.

```
$external = App\External::first()->pluck('data');

$email = $external['email']; // katie.jane@example.com
```

Comment: `pluck` returns a Collection

Comment: >>> $email = $external['email']
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: email in /home/vagrant/code/{domain_name_censored}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php on line 1290
>>>

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get the data for one record use the cast attribute as an array:

```
// one External record
$external = App\External::first();

$email = $external->data['email'];
$id = $external->data['id'];
```

Comment: This works thanks... However, how do you return all emails too?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `pluck()`.

if you want to access email from the data of an External.

```php
$email = App\External::first()->data['email'];
```

**UPDATE**

to get all the emails.

```php
$emails = App\External::all()
    ->map(function($external) {
        return $external->data['email'];
    });
```

Comment: This works thanks... However, how do you return all emails too?

Comment: to do so you can get `all()` and `map()` result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$external = collect(App\External::all()->pluck('data'))->pluck('email')->all();
```